# Accessing field on original C struct in Go

Tags: opencv, go

I'm trying to use OpenCV from Go. OpenCV defines a struct `CvMat` that has a `data` field:

```
typedef struct CvMat
{
    ...
    union
    {
        uchar* ptr;
        short* s;
    } data;
}
```

I'm using the go bindings for opencv found [here](http://github.com/lazywei/go-opencv). This has a type alias for `CvMat`:

```
type Mat C.CvMat
```

Now I have a `Mat` object and I want to access the `data` field on it. How can I do this? If I try to access `_data`, it doesn't work. I printed out the fields on the `Mat` object with the `reflect` package and got this:

```
...
{data github.com/lazywei/go-opencv/opencv [8]uint8  24 [5] false}
...
```

So there is a `data` field on it, but it's not even the same type. It's an array of 8 `uint8`s! I'm looking for a `uchar*` that is much longer than 8 characters. How do I get to this `uchar`?

Comment: The go bindings in cxtype.go add Mat.Get and Mat.Set for manipulating the matrix. The data field inside CvMat contains a 64bit pointer to the actual matrix values in an array of float64 (doubles), or float32 (float) depending on the value found in the `type` field. The actual definition for these is in cxtypes.h as inline functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't do this without modifying `go-opencv`.  There are a few impediments here:

1. When you import a package, [you can only use identifiers that have been exported](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers).  In this case, `data` does not start with an upper case letter, so is not exported.
2. Even if it was an exported identifier, you would have trouble because Go does not support unions.  So instead the field has been represented by a byte array that matches the size of the underlying C union (8 bytes in this case, which matches the size of a 64-bit pointer).
3. Lastly, [it is strongly recommended not to expose `cgo` types from packages](http://golang.org/doc/go1.3#cgo).  So even in cases like this where it may be possible to directly access the underlying C structure, I would recommend against it.

Ideally `go-opencv` would provide an accessor for the information you are after (presumably one that could check which branch of the union is in use, rather than silently returning bad data.  I would suggest you either file a bug report on the package (possibly with a patch), or create a private copy with the required modifications if you need the feature right away.